# Convert a Deployment template.json and parameters.json to AzureRM objects

Tags: azure-resource-manager

If I'm given a template.json and a corresponding paramaters.json file, is there a way to generate a single JSON file that has all references resolved & ARM functions evaluated?

E.g., if I have something like below in the first snippet, is there a way to generate a JSON that would have the ARM function fully evaluated to get the second snippet?

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
  "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "properties": {
    "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]",
    "dnsSettings": {
      "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
    }
  }
},


{
  "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
  "name": "ProdPublicIPAddress",
  "location": "North Europe",
  "properties": {
    "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
    "dnsSettings": {
      "domainNameLabel": "Test"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: eh, what problem are you trying to solve? this doesnt make any sense, unfortunately

Comment: I'm trying to see if I can programmatically manage my infrastructure by reading  ARM deployment files (template & parameters) to instantiate classes under the Microsoft.Azure.Management.*.Models namespace.

Comment: I'd think you'd have to create a parser for that, nothing built-in in Azure, maybe Test-AzResourceGroupDeployment` with `-Debug` would show the result, although I doubt it

Comment: Yeah, Test-AzResourceGroupDeployment has its limitations. Is the parser in the ARM engine open-source?